# Nuxt.js - can I use Universal Rendering Mode and Static/JAMStack hosting together

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I'm in the process of creating a Nuxt application with the CLI. It asks me about the Rendering Mode and the Deployment Target. I wonder if it makes sense to select Universal (SSR/SSG) for the rendering mode and Static/JAMStack hosting together. Do I need to select Server (Node.js hosting) when I choose Universal rendering mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wondered this same thing, I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336570/whats-the-real-difference-between-target-static-and-target-server-in-nuxt) that would seem to indicate that you can use  SSR mode with Static target.