# nuxt build vs generate

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm not sure when to use what.

with `nuxt build` you get two directories(`client` & `server`) that means you are actually deploying node.js server(i.e. express, right?)

with `nuxt generate` you get `.html`

It seems both ways you can have good SEO which nuxt aims at. And to me, `nuxt generate` option seems more consize since it doesn't envolve server.

What am I missing here? Why should I use `nuxt build` and get server code mixed up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the real difference between target: 'static' and target: 'server' in Nuxt 2.14 universal mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336570/whats-the-real-difference-between-target-static-and-target-server-in-nuxt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is shown in the docs here:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/commands/

`nuxt build`: Build your application with webpack and minify the JS & CSS (for production).
`nuxt generate`: Build the application and generate every route as a HTML file (used for static hosting).
Josh

Comment: as an addition you can say that nuxt generate will not exist anymore from nuxt 3 on. https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/515

Comment: in nuxt.config.ts    add   "ssr: false,
  target: 'static' ", and then use   nuxt generate